# how to get the index path of a cell from a collection view, from a textfield using textFieldDidBeginediting

Tags: swift, collectionview

I have made a collection view which is populated with textfields. I've got the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` working. I've assigned the textfield in the cell for item at indexpath as delegate. the question is how do i get the `indexPath.row` in the field that i have selected in the code below? any help would be much appreciated

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    print("")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert `CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)` to a point relative to the collection view's frame of reference (`textField.convertPoint(point: yourZeroPoint, toView: yourCollectionView)`), then use `yourCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint` to get the `indexPath` at that point.

Comment: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    
   
   let zeroPoint = textField.convertPoint(textField.center, fromView: collview1)
    
    
    print(zeroPoint)
  print(collview1.indexPathForItemAtPoint(zeroPoint))
    
    } // i get the point for the textfield but the index path is always nil? any idea how to fix this

Comment: I would say that you've got it the wrong way round - `let point: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(point: textField.center, toView: collview1); let indexPath: NSIndexPath? = collview1.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point);` Note `toView` rather than `fromView` — you want the point in the collection view coordinate space.

Comment: func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    
   let point: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(textField.center, toView: collview1);

    
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath? = collview1.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
    
    print(point)
    } //    nope still no index path still returns nil, the coordinates show up right just index path isn't showing??

Answer (score 0):

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

   let point: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: collview1);


    let indexPath:NSIndexPath? = collview1.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)

    print(point)
    print(indexPath)

}
```

collview1 is a collection view outlet